# How to Map Composite Primary key in JPA

Tags: jpa, mapping, one-to-many

```
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "roll_no", nullable = false)
    private long rollNo;
    @Column(name = "enrollment_no", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String enrollmentNo;
}


   @Entity
   @Table(name = "subject")
   public class Subject {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "subject_code", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String code;// course code
}
```

I have the above two classes.
I want to create a StudentMarks class for below database table
student_marks(student_id, marks_id, marks, passing_status);

I tried this

````
@Embeddable
public class StudentMarksId implements Serializable {

    private Long studentId;
    private Long subjected;
     //getter and setter
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "student_marks")
public class StudentMarks implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4428298147790767663L;

    @EmbeddedId
    @Id
    @JoinColumns({ 
        @JoinColumn(name = "subject_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
    private StudentMarksId id;

    
    private List<Subject> subjects;
    private List<Student> students;

    @Column(name = "marks", nullable = false)
    private int marks;

    @Column(name = "passing_status", nullable = false)
    private String passingStatus;// pass or fail
 }```

I want to map student and subjects to student_marks.
````

Comment: There are many tutorials on composite PKs, which have you been looking at? You cannot mark a single property (id) as EmbeddedId AND as an Id with join columns. Don't you need to have a single references to a Student and Subject in this entity somewhere? I don't see why you'd have them both as collections in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to map this. One is:

```
public class StudentMarksId implements Serializable {
    private Long studentId;
    private Long subjected;
     //getter and setter
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "student_marks")
@IdClass(StudentMarksId.class)
public class StudentMarks implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4428298147790767663L;
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "subject_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Subject subject;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Student student;

    @Column(name = "marks", nullable = false)
    private int marks;

    @Column(name = "passing_status", nullable = false)
    private String passingStatus;// pass or fail
}
```

Another might be to map the StudentMarksId as an embeddable in the entity as well:

```
@Embeddable
public class StudentMarksId implements Serializable {
    private Long studentId;
    private Long subjected;
     //getter and setter
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "student_marks")
@IdClass(StudentMarksId.class)
public class StudentMarks implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4428298147790767663L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private StudentMarksId id;

    @MapsId("subjected")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "subject_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Subject subjects;

    @MapsId("studentId")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Student student;

    @Column(name = "marks", nullable = false)
    private int marks;

    @Column(name = "passing_status", nullable = false)
    private String passingStatus;// pass or fail
}
```

Comment: private Subject subjects; and  private Student students; will be list and one to many annotation ?

Comment: No - This is essentially a relation table between Student and courses with the extra bit of information of a mark in the course. I've mapped them as a single instance, which defaults to OneToOne mapping since there is only one StudentMarks instance per Student-course pairing. You might be confused with a OneToMany with a ManyToOne back pointer. This StudentMarks.student relationship should be marked as the ManyToOne, as many StudentMarks point at the same Student (and many StudentMarks point at the same course). I'll update that in the answer.